# What's some other songs like Slider Race from Mario 64?

Tags: similar-artists

I'm making a video for my friend of the funniest FarCry 5 clips I've recorded, and I've put it to [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f64nXt1z4XU), but the song lasts for less than half the video. I can't think of any appropriate songs to put in, so I was wondering if you guys might've had any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ["Jungle Japes"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYxqTYIi56I) from the Donkey Kong 64 soundtrack. I've used this before in a video of my own, highlighting funny CS:GO clips and footage. Hope it fits for your video!

Comment: Oh that’s good, I ended up going with Spanish flea and 12th street rag, but I think jungle japes and slider race will be in part 2